# Mockito - verify method call according to another objects state

Tags: java, tdd, mockito

I am currently working my way through he book "Growing Object Oriented Design - guided by tests". The authors are the creators of JMock which is used within the book. Since Mockito currently has the most expressive (readable) API I am using Mockito instead of JMock.

For most examples this worked great so far with much less code. It is interesting though to see how the APIs evolved over the time and frameworks (JMock -> EasyMock -> Mockito) and still base on the same concepts.

Anyway: **I need to verify that a mock-method is called at the time when a another objects state has a certain value.**

```
public class TestSomething{

    private MyMockedInterface mock;
    private States state;

    @Test
    public void testMethod()
    {
        // I need something like
        when(state.equals(value)).verify(mock).method()

        sut.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when(T methodCall) cannot handle object comparison. A assertEquals after sut.something() wont help me here because the state might have changed within doSomething several times.

I am quite sure there must be a way to address this. Would be strange if the old JMock had a feature Mockito doesnt :-) ... I just cant find it.

Answer (score 1):

What  you need is something called an `Answer` - this is an object that wraps a little chunk of code that will run when your method is called.  The syntax for using an `Answer` is described at http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#11

In your `Answer`, you can use asserts to check that the state of the other objects is what you need it to be.  Then at the end, you can do your `verify`, just to ensure that the method was called.